# pycouchdb delete specific documents JS function

Tags: javascript, python, couchdb

I have seen the documentation of py-couchdb. I also saw some js functions for removing documents from the database, so I tried to recreate them for my couch database. After the insertion of some data (1.2gb in csv, ~12gb in database i wonder why...) I tried to make some queries on the dataset.

Selects were ok. But when I tried to delete specific docs the queries did not work as expected. Here are the queries:

```
  map_func = "function(doc) { if (doc['Year'] == 2015) emit(doc._id, null);}"
  map_func_2 = "function(doc) { if (doc['Year'] == 2015) emit(null, doc._rev);}"
  map_func_3 = "function(doc) { if (doc['Year'] == 2015) emit(doc._deleted='true',null);}"
  map_func_4 = "function(doc) { if (doc['Year'] == 2015) emit(doc.deleted='true',null);}"
  map_func_5 = "function(doc) { if (doc['Year'] == 2015) emit(doc.deleted=true,null);}"
  map_func_6 = "function(doc) { if (doc['Year'] == 2015) emit(doc._deleted:'true',null);}"
```

Then I called each function and checked if the docs were deleted(from map_func).

```
  print "Quering for Deleting Year = 2015"
  t = time.time()
  db.temporary_query(map_func_3)
  print float(time.time() - t)

  print "Quering for Year = 2015"
  t = time.time()
  print len(list(db.temporary_query(map_func)))
  print float(time.time() - t)
```

But not even any of them actually delete or hide the specified docs. I also tried another approach, doing the deletions from python.

```
for doc in db.all(as_list=True):
      if doc['Year'] == 2015:
          db.delete(doc)
```

The problem here is that the Database.all() function caches the entire data and I get memory overflow errors.

Comment: To help me understand more about your problem, can you tell me if there was a particular reason for choosing pycouchdb? Also, what is your level of experience with couchdb?

Comment: I want to evaluate different types of databases like SQL vs NoSql. I have compared so far Mongodb & Sqlite3 . And i was thinking to evaluate the couchdb too. I have 0 experience with the above database, I read the documentations and some examples and try to set it up. I inserted all the data and now I want to do some queries to the database , see the latency of each query etc...

Comment: In that case, it may be best to write questions on stackoverflow for each thing you are trying to test with couchdb to make sure you are using the most performant methods. For example, the second temporary query in your question will create an index when you execute it which will be much slower than if you had predefined the index as a view within couchdb.  Also, depending on your use case, it may make sense to create a separate database per year.  That will make dropping years very quick because you can drop the whole database.